# (Pandas Dataframes) How to have rows share the same column from a dataframe with repeated column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Current Dataframe:

```
    Name       Age  City    Name     Age  City
0   Andy       18   Ely     Laura    18   Ely
1   Joel       39   Odessa  Claudia  36   Odessa
2   Terrence   50   Horsens Lilly    51   Horsens
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
    Name       Age  City
0   Andy       18   Ely
    Laura      18   Ely
1   Joel       39   Odessa
    Claudia    36   Odessa
2   Terrence   50   Horsens
    Lilly      51   Horsens
```

I assume you'd have to use groupby or something? It seems like it would be simple to do, and it probably is, but I'm just starting out and I can't figure it out.

Comment: does pandas not automatically rename your column names? do you have `Name, Name.1, Name.2` etc ?

Comment: It did on the initial df, where there were 2 columns named "Name Age City" and "Name Age City.1" 
afterwards I divided them into 6, and had to leave them like that because it was a requirement from the exercise (It's from an exercise).

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is always of the same length, we can use a simple function to concat the dataframe.

we can chunk your dataframe into parts using the method `np.array_split` by passing in your target column length, in this instance three.

```
import numpy as np

def concat_dataframe(dataframe, original_column_length):
    """takes a dataframe and a length of original columns then returns a concenated dataframe.
    dataframe : your dataframe
    column_length : original columns number i.e City, Age, Name
    """
    col_len = len(dataframe.columns) / original_column_length
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.concatenate([dataframe[col].values for col in np.array_split(df.columns, col_len)]),
        columns = dataframe.iloc[:,:original_column_length].columns.tolist(),
        index = df.index.tolist() * int(col_len)
    ).sort_index()
```

## Test.

```
print(df)

       Name  Age     City   Name.1  Age.1   City.1
0      Andy   18      Ely    Laura     18      Ely
1      Joel   39   Odessa  Claudia     36   Odessa
2  Terrence   50  Horsens    Lilly     51  Horsens


print(concat_dataframe(df,3)) 

       Name Age     City
0      Andy  18      Ely
0     Laura  18      Ely
1      Joel  39   Odessa
1   Claudia  36   Odessa
2  Terrence  50  Horsens
2     Lilly  51  Horsens
```

## using `Stack` and `cumcount`

another method would be to create a psuedo index to reshape your dataframe from a duplicate index (your columns)

```
print(df)

       Name  Age     City     Name  Age     City
0      Andy   18      Ely    Laura   18      Ely
1      Joel   39   Odessa  Claudia   36   Odessa
2  Terrence   50  Horsens    Lilly   51  Horsens

s = df.stack().to_frame()
s[1] = s.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount()
df_new = s.set_index(1,append=True).unstack([0,1]).T.droplevel([0,1],axis=0)

print(df_new[['Name','Age','City']])

       Name Age     City
0      Andy  18      Ely
0     Laura  18      Ely
1      Joel  39   Odessa
1   Claudia  36   Odessa
2  Terrence  50  Horsens
2     Lilly  51  Horsens
```

Comment: But my duplicate columns aren't .1, the're exactly the same name. I don't know if that affects your function there. Also, I was looking to keep the nº of indexes with double rows like I showed on the OP.

Comment: @kalkstein you can manually set the index, the other method would be to use `stack` names do not matter.

Comment: Stack isn't working it butchers the entire dataframe. And I need to have the default pandas index.

EDIT: I see you've updated the answer, seems stack by itself wasn't enough. I didn't know what other functions could go with it.

Comment: @kalkstein then your example isn't representative to your dataframe, please read [mcve] additionally the first function has been modified to add in your default index.

Comment: Would you like me to update my post and paste the code that leads my current dataframe?

Comment: I think if we go from the start and deal with the issue upstream it's easier to fix rather than me trying to guess what your dataframe looks like (I worked with your example and was able to get your desired output) can you post your input dataframe?

Comment: It's from two csv files. It gets processed through a function before because of the first exercise, so I won't be able to change that one.